# Circle and two points

Tags: geometry

So, circle $(x-4)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$ and two points $A=(-4,3)$ and $B=(-2,5)$ are given. I have to find circle that intersects with given circle in one point and passes through points $A$ and $B$.

I know that there are two circles that pass through points $A$ and $B$ and intersect with given circle in one point, but I just can't find solution. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible if the circle is supposed to lie in the same plane as the given circle. $A$ is inside the circle, and $B$ is outside. Every circle in the same plane that meets the interior and exterior of a given circle must meet the circle in two points.

Do you have a typographical error? Are $A$ and $B$ supposed to lie on the same side (interior/exterior) of the circle?

Answer (score 0):

Circles intersecting in the only point are tangent to each other.
Your circle has the following equation: $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$. After putting coordinates of $A$ and $B$ we have two equations and need one more to solve the system. It can be given from the statement that circles are tangent. You need to write equations for both circles as $y = y_1(x)$ for the first circle and $y = y_1(x)$ for the second. There will be square roots with $\pm$, so you have to choose correct signs depending on which quarters the circles are tangent to each other. Then you have to find such $a$, $b$ and $R$ that equation for $x$: $y_1(x) = y_2(x)$ has the only solution.

I agree with @MPW comment, you can't construct a circle passing through given points tangent to the first one, so please check the problem statement.